# Can't decrypt drive after upgrading from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 using instructions from this tutorial :

https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-version/

When trying to decrypt my drive, I'm not able to go further than :

cryptsetup (sda5_crypt): set up successfully

My Desktop "freeze" there.

I have the same issue even with a new clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC with fulldisk encryption.

Anyone using fulldisk encryption can confirm if it work or not on 18.04 ?

My initial post for this issue began on linuxquestions.org :

https://www.linuxquestions.org/quest...-a-4175628984/

thank you

Comment: To answer your question, full disk encryption on a clean install works for me on 18.04, but sorry I can’t be more help.